# How to start processes in parallel in bash via a loop

Tags: bash

I have a script that makes 3 application calls at one instance of the script run.
the code is

```
while IFS= read -r inp1; do
    IFS= read -r inp2
    IFS= read -r inp3
    application_name "$inp1" &
    [[ -n $file2 ]] && application_name "$inp2" &
    [[ -n $file3 ]] && application_name "$inp3" &
    wait
done < list_of_files
```

The list of file contains many files. like

```
cat list_of_files
 inp1
 inp2
 inp3
 inp4
 inp5
 inp6
 ...
```

and so on.

This code actually works quite well and the "3" processes are started in one go.
Now the requirement is the if in the code, the first application call is done, the 4th input file should be used to call the application.
and when the second process(inp2) is done, then the 5th input file should be used to call the application and so on.

But, the condition is only 3 processes can run at one time.

I tried to modify the code to

```
while IFS= read -r inp1; do
    IFS= read -r inp2
    IFS= read -r inp3
    IFS= read -r inp4
    IFS= read -r inp5
    IFS= read -r inp6
    application_name "$inp1" &
    P_ID=$!
    while kill -0 "$P_ID" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
        pflag=True
    done
    if [[ $pflag == "False" ]] ; then   
        application_name "$inp4" &
    fi
    [[ -n $file2 ]] && application_name "$inp2" &
    while kill -0 "$P_ID" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
        pflag=True
    done
    if [[ $pflag == "False" ]] ; then   
        application_name "$inp5" &
    fi
    [[ -n $file3 ]] && application_name "$inp3" &
    while kill -0 "$P_ID" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
        pflag=True
    done
    if [[ $pflag == "False" ]] ; then   
        application_name "$inp6" &
    fi
    wait
done < list_of_files
```

But in this case,the execution waits for the 1st process to finish and start the second one.
and all the processes are started one by one, and not 3 at a time.

How can i modify my code, to start 3 processes at the same time, but when the 1st process out of the 3 is done, start the second one, and 2nd out of 3 is dones start the 5th one and so on.
so that the CPU is not idle.

Comment: **GNU Parallel** is the best tool for the job, IMHO. Try something like `parallel -j3 -a list_of_files application_name`

Comment: There's a very easy-to-read PDF on **GNU Parallel** here https://zenodo.org/record/1146014/files/GNU_Parallel_2018.pdf?download=1

Comment: Thank you, i dont have this tool installed, and i cannot install it without admin rights. I am looking for another way :)

Comment: Not sure understand that - it's just a Perl script. Aren't you allowed to run scripts?

Comment: @anonymous Please read https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/ Do any of these scenarios apply to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may keep the last three PIDs of application instances you started (in the snippet of code below, I call these PIDs: last, penultimate, antepenultimate)

You start ONE single instance of your application in the loop.

You'll always wait for the oldest before starting another one. (modifying the list of the 3 last PIDs launched every time you start a new one).

This would give something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
last=0
penultimate=0
antepenultimate=0


while IFS= read -r inp; do
    antepenultimate=$penultimate
    penultimate=$last
    ./ma_fonction.sh "$inp" &
    last=$! 
    if [ "$antepenultimate" != "0" ] ; then 
        wait "$antepenultimate" 
    fi
done < list_of_files
```

I made a "dummy" application ma_fonction.sh which is as follows (don't forget to make it executable with **chmod +x ma_function.sh**):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo begin $1
sleep $((1+$1%3)) # variable delay depending on the number of the file
echo end $1
```

I filled up the file list_of_files with a sequence of numbers between 1 and 20:

```
seq 1 20 > list_of_files
```

And then I launched my script:

```
bash test.sh
```

I got the following output:

```
begin 3
begin 2
begin 1
end 3
end 1
begin 4
end 2
begin 6
begin 5
end 4
begin 7
end 6
end 7
end 5
begin 9
begin 8
begin 10
end 9
end 10
end 8
begin 12
begin 11
begin 13
end 12
end 13
end 11
begin 16
begin 15
begin 14
end 15
end 16
end 14
begin 19
begin 17
begin 18
end 18
end 19
end 17
begin 20
end 20
```

NB: It might seem weird that the #3 is started before #2 and #1, but as all three processes are started at once, at the beginning, the display output (which is buffered) comes out with an unpredictable order...

The first three loops, the "oldest" PID in antepenultimate will be 0. So you'll start the first 3 processes immediately, and then you'll wait for #1 to finish before starting #4 and so forth...

Comment: this code combined with my code, starts 6 processes at the same time :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it, and (as often with bash), I made an error... the line "antepenultimate=penultimate" is a bug: it puts the text penultimate into antepenultimate when I meant: antepenultimate=$penultimate... I correct my post with the full (working) example.

Answer (score 1):

GNU xargs has `-P` option. Typically you do:

```
xargs -P$(nproc) -n1 -d'\n' application_name < list_of_files
```

`nproc` is from GNU coreutils and returns the number of processors on a machine.

---

> How to start processes in parallel in bash via a loop

That's simple - bash has `wait -n` option that's very handy, see `help wait`. You see m to me like you nowhere in your scripts keep **count** of the processes you had run. You have to keep count of them.

```
max=$(nproc)
count=0
while IFS= read -r file; do
     application_name "$file" &
     # I assume ++count will never overflow...
     if ((++count >= max)); then
         wait -n    # TODO: handle error
     fi
done < list_of_files
wait
```

Comment: This solution is better than my own proposal, since I was always waiting for the oldest subprocess to finish before starting a new one when yours is waiting for the first one to finish before starting a new one, which is obviously better. Thanks for reminding me of "wait -n" I had forgotten about the option.